# CanvasJS Load Data Dynamically MVC Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, asp.net-core-mvc, canvasjs

I am using asp.net core MVC to create dynamic charts for my application. I am using CanvasJS to draw the chart.

I would like to draw the chart data based on the selected parameters from the screen. So,  I have a dropdownlist and a datatable that defines which data to retrieve from the database.

Problem is that my chart is not loaded after I click  `UpdateChart` button. However when I debug the application and as per the console logs, the js function is working but it doesn't update the  `data` inside the chart.

My View is like

```
<script>
   var chart;
   function myFunction() {
       console.log("Inside My Function_1");
       chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart-container", {
           zoomEnabled: true,
           title: {
               text: '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartText)'//"My Text"
           },
           axisX: {
               title: "chart updates every 2 secs",
               crosshair: {
                   enabled: true,
                   snapToDataPoint: true
               }
           },
           axisY: {
               crosshair: {
                   enabled: true,
                   snapToDataPoint: true,
                   valueFormatString: "#,##0"
               }
           },
           toolTip: {
               shared: true
           },
           legend: {
               dockInsidePlotArea: true,
               verticalAlign: "top",
               horizontalAlign: "right"
           },
           data: [ @Html.Raw(ViewBag.AllData) ]
   });
       console.log("Inside My Function_2");
       chart.render();
       console.log("Inside My Function_3");

       }
   window.onload = myFunction;


   function GetData() {
       var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
       var data = table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("UpdateChart","Home")', //"/Home/UpdateChart",
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           data: data,
           dataType: "html",
           success: function (result) {
               console.log("Container remove called.");
               chart.destroy();
               //$('#chart-container').remove();
               //console.log("Container removed called.");
               //$('#graph-container').append('<div id="chart-container" class="chart-area-big"><div>');
               //console.log("Container appened again.");

               myFunction();
               console.log(result);
           }
       });
   }

</script>

       <div id="graph-container" class="card shadow mb-4">
           <div class="d-block card-header py-3">
               <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Chart</h6>
           </div>
           <div id="chart-container" class="chart-area-big">

           </div>
       </div>
<button type="button" id="getDataBtn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="GetData();">Update Chart</button>
```

And my controller is like

```
public IActionResult ChartNew()
        {
            ChartRepository repository = new ChartRepository();
            GeneralObjects.ServiceResponse response = repository.GetChartData();
            List<Devices> tmpList = repository.GetCustomerDevices();
            ViewData["CustomerDevices"] = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList(tmpList, "Id", "SerialNumber");

            string query = "SELECT mqttpacket_1606008363.id, datatypes.data_name ,mqttpacket_1606008363.data_value,packetinformation.inserted_time  FROM mqttpacket_1606008363 JOIN packetinformation ON mqttpacket_1606008363.packet_id = packetinformation.id JOIN datatypes ON mqttpacket_1606008363.data_type_id = datatypes.id WHERE packetinformation.inserted_time BETWEEN '2021-03-04 10:44:55.544398' AND '2021-03-05 10:49:55.544398' AND data_type_id = 5 ORDER BY inserted_time asc;";
            response = repository.GetChartData(query);

            ViewBag.ChartText = $"Reading Values of {ViewBag.DataPointName1} and {ViewBag.DataPointName2}";
            ViewBag.AllData = response.This_Object;


            System.Data.DataTable dt = repository.GetDataTypes();
            return View(dt);
        }
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        public GeneralObjects.RES UpdateChart()
        {
            
            ChartRepository repository = new ChartRepository();

            string deviceSerialNo = HttpContext.Session.GetString("currentSerialNumber") != null ? HttpContext.Session.GetString("currentSerialNumber").ToString() : "1606008363";
            string selectedDataTypes = HttpContext.Request.Form["chkBox"].ToString();

            string query = repository.PrepSelectQuery(selectedDataTypes, deviceSerialNo, "2021-03-05 10:44:55.544398", "2021-03-11 12:44:55.544398");

            GeneralObjects.ServiceResponse response = repository.GetChartData(query);

            if (response.Return_Code != 0)
                return GeneralObjects.RES.R_NOK;

            TempData["SuccessMSG"] = "Successfull!";
            ViewBag.AllData = response.This_Object;

            return GeneralObjects.RES.R_OKK;
        }
```

For instance when I select the parameters from the screen  `response.ThisObject` Is like

```
{type: "line",
markerType:"none",
xValueType:"dateTime",
xValueFormatString:"DDDD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss",
name:'Discharge',
showInLegend: true,
dataPoints:[{"x":1614937497000.0,"y":315.0},{"x":1614937502000.0,"y":315.0},{"x":1614937507000.0,"y":317.0},{"x":1614937517000.0,"y":320.0},{"x":1614937523000.0,"y":320.0},{"x":1614937528000.0,"y":322.0},{"x":1614937533000.0,"y":322.0},{"x":1614937537000.0,"y":323.0},{"x":1614937543000.0,"y":325.0},{"x":1614937547000.0,"y":325.0},{"x":1614937552000.0,"y":327.0},{"x":1614937563000.0,"y":328.0},{"x":1614937573000.0,"y":330.0},{"x":1614937583000.0,"y":331.0},{"x":1614937588000.0,"y":331.0},{"x":1614937593000.0,"y":332.0},{"x":1614937598000.0,"y":332.0},{"x":1614937603000.0,"y":333.0},{"x":1614937608000.0,"y":334.0}]}
{type: "line",
markerType:"none",
xValueType:"dateTime",
xValueFormatString:"DDDD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss",
name:'subcooling',
showInLegend: true,
dataPoints:[{"x":1614937507000.0,"y":22.0},{"x":1614937513000.0,"y":22.0},{"x":1614937517000.0,"y":24.0},{"x":1614937528000.0,"y":23.0},{"x":1614937537000.0,"y":24.0},{"x":1614937558000.0,"y":26.0},{"x":1614937568000.0,"y":25.0},{"x":1614937573000.0,"y":23.0},{"x":1614937578000.0,"y":23.0},{"x":1614937603000.0,"y":22.0},{"x":1614937613000.0,"y":21.0}]}
```

I got this value right before the `return GeneralObjects.RES.R_OKK;` However, It doesn't get updated...

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not store the data in ViewBag when do the update with ajax, because the data in ViewBag will not change in the view.

I suggest you could directly return the data in the update action.

A simple example changed from [Official Site](https://canvasjs.com/asp-net-mvc-charts/json-data-api-ajax-chart/)

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>

<button type="button" id="getDataBtn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Update();">Update Chart</button>
@section scripts{

    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var dataPoints = [];
        var chart
        function addData(data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({
                    x: new Date(data[i].x),
                    y: data[i].y
                });
            }

            chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                animationEnabled: true,
                theme: "light2",
                title: {
                    text: "Lenovo Group Stock Price-2017"
                },
                axisY: {
                    title: "In HK$",
                    titleFontSize: 24
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "line",
                    yValueFormatString: "HK$#,###",
                    dataPoints: dataPoints
                }]
            });
            chart.render();
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/home/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    addData(data)
                }
            })
        }

        function Update() {
            dataPoints = [];
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/home/json2',
                success: function (data) {
                    addData(data)
                }
            })
        
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ContentResult JSON()
{
    List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1481999400000, 4.67));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1482604200000, 4.7));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1483209000000, 4.96));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1483813800000, 5.12));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1484418600000, 5.08));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1485023400000, 5.11));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1485628200000, 5));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1486233000000, 5.2));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1486837800000, 4.7));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1487442600000, 4.74));

    JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints, _jsonSetting), "application/json");
}

public ContentResult JSON2()
{
    List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1481999400000, 4.67));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1482604200000, 4.7));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1483209000000, 4.96));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1483813800000, 5.12));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1484418600000, 5.08));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1485023400000, 5.11));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1485628200000, 5));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1486233000000, 5.2));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1486837800000, 4.7));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1487442600000, 4.74));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1488047400000, 4.67));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1488652200000, 4.66));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1489257000000, 4.86));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1489861800000, 4.91));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1490466600000, 5.12));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1491071400000, 5.4));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1491676200000, 5.08));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1492281000000, 5.05));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1492885800000, 4.98));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1493490600000, 4.89));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1494095400000, 4.9));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1494700200000, 4.95));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1495305000000, 4.88));
    dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(1495909800000, 5.07));
    JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints, _jsonSetting), "application/json");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and effort. But here the thing is my data types can be selected differently in each update button clicks. That means for instance the user can select the checkboxes "x,y,z" as datapoint at first load and then can select "x,t,w" in the second select and also can change the duration of the graph. 
But I think I can integrate the returning complete data from the function instead of using a Viewbag. Thanks

Comment: That's it! The main problem here is the ViewBag.

Comment: Yea. I just validated by dumping the ViewBag value on the console and saw that value doesn't change. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to render the chart before the client side could receive the data from the back-end. The data from the back-end just isn't there yet, each time you click on the button, that's why it renders without anything.

Try calling `chart.render()` after the data has been received from the back-end.

Comment: yea, that makes sense. But I tried to call ```chart.render()``` in AJAX ```success:``` and the result is the same.